# Получить счетчик i в функции

Tags: javascript, framework7

Я использую framework7.
Пытаюсь создать Action Sheet, но столкнулся с проблемой.
Мой код:

```
<script>
    return {
        methods: {
            selectCurrency: function () {
                var $ = this.$;
                var app = this.$app;
                var self = this;
                app.preloader.show();
                app.request({
                    url: app.data.api.site + '/index.php?route=tazboapi/locals/list_currencies',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    method: "GET",
                    success: function (successCurrencies) {
                        app.preloader.hide();
                        var currenciesObj = JSON.parse(successCurrencies);
                        var currenciesList = [{text:"Выбор валюты", label: true}];
                        for (var i = 0; i < currenciesObj.currencies.length; i++) {
                            curObject = {
                              text:currenciesObj.currencies[i].title,
                              onClick:function () {
                                app.dialog.alert('Cancel clicked' + i);
                              }
                            };
                            currenciesList.push(curObject);
                        }
                        currenciesList.push({text:"Закрыть", color:'red', close:true});
                        // Select
                        var currencies = app.actions.create({
                            buttons: currenciesList
                        });
                        currencies.open();
                    },
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

JSON который я обрабатываю:

```
{"event":"success","currencies":[{"title":"Euro","code":"EUR","symbol_left":"","symbol_right":"\u20ac"},{"title":"Pound Sterling","code":"GBP","symbol_left":"\u00a3","symbol_right":""},{"title":"US Dollar","code":"USD","symbol_left":"$","symbol_right":""},{"title":"\u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u044c","code":"RUB","symbol_left":"","symbol_right":"\u20bd"}]}
```

Когда я пытаюсь получить переменную i в функции обработчика onClick:function я всегда получаю i=4.
Почему и как мне получить корректно переменную i в функции обработчика?

Comment: Где там закрывашка про захват переменных?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015589/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0/1015600#1015600 — та же история)

Answer (score 0):

F7 тут ни при чем, это в JS:

`for (var i = 0; ...`  → `for (let i = 0; ...`