# Почему событие срабатывает только для последнего элемента?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объявлений, к каждому из которых генерируется метка на карте и карточка к ней. При клике на метку, должна отобразиться соответствующая ей карточка. Следующий код срабатывает как надо:

```
 adsList.forEach(item => {
                var pin = renderPin(item);
                var ad = window.card.renderAd(item);
                pin.addEventListener('click', function (evtClick) {                  
                    window.pin.openedPin.classList.add("map__pin--active");
                    ad.classList.remove("hidden");
                })
            });
```

Но чтобы ограничить число меток на карте, я хочу воспользоваться обычным циклом for и получается следующее:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < PIN_NUMBER; i++){
                var pin = renderPin(adsList[i]);
                var ad = window.card.renderAd(adsList[i]);
                pin.addEventListener('click', function (evtClick) {                  
                    window.pin.openedPin.classList.add("map__pin--active");
                    ad.classList.remove("hidden");
                })
            });
```

В этом случае при клике на любую метку отображается та карточка, которая была последней в цикле. Может быть, кто-нибудь может объяснить с чем связано такое поведение?

Comment: Пробуйте заменить `var` на `let` )

Comment: @opt Спасибо, сработало! А не могли бы, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему использование var все поломало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь не важно, какой код, важно поведение var в цикле, поэтому примеры будут с другим кодом. Допустим, навешиваем событие на кнопки, а при клике - они должны что-то делать с числом `i`:

```js
var bubu = document.querySelectorAll('.bubu');

for( var i = 0; i < bubu.length; i++ ){
  bubu[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log( i );
  });
}
console.log( i );
```

```html
<button class="bubu">0000</button>
<button class="bubu">1111</button>
<button class="bubu">2222</button>
<button class="bubu">3333</button>
<button class="bubu">4444</button>
```

Хотелось, чтобы каждая кнопка выводила свой номер - а выводит 5. Это потому что цикл практически моментально сработав - вешает обработчики на все кнопки и заканчивает свою работу. А уже потом, в момент клика, `i` даже вне цикла, для всех равен 5.

Если не хочется использовать let, можно "поймать" значение `i` через запущенную на месте функцию:

```js
var bubu = document.querySelectorAll('.bubu');

for( var i = 0; i < bubu.length; i++ ){
  (function(i){
    //Здесь уже i - не тот же i из цикла, а уже внутренняя переменная для функции
    //и она равна...
    bubu[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      console.log( i );
    });
  })(i);//этому i, который получен прямо из цикла, в момент его выполнения.
}
console.log( i );
```

```html
<button class="bubu">0000</button>
<button class="bubu">1111</button>
<button class="bubu">2222</button>
<button class="bubu">3333</button>
<button class="bubu">4444</button>
```

А let на каждом круге цикла - заново создается и "виден" только на этом круге цикла. Вне цикла - вообще будет undefined:

```js
var bubu = document.querySelectorAll('.bubu');

for( let i = 0; i < bubu.length; i++ ){
  bubu[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log( i );
  });
}
console.log( i ); // ошибка, i is not defined
```

```html
<button class="bubu">0000</button>
<button class="bubu">1111</button>
<button class="bubu">2222</button>
<button class="bubu">3333</button>
<button class="bubu">4444</button>
```

Comment: console.log( i ); // ошибка, i is not defined, потому что вы es6 не знаете, нужно let вынести за фигурные скобки. let i = 0; for( ; i < bubu.length; i++ ){

Comment: @АндрейСобченюк угу, так и было задумано для демо) Недорассказал в ответе.

Answer (score -1):

```js
// es6

  const bubu_parent = document.querySelector('.bubu_parent');

  const buttons = bubu_parent.querySelectorAll('button');

  bubu_parent.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {

    const result = Array.from(buttons).findIndex(el => el === e.target);

       console.log(result);
   });
```

```html
 <div class="bubu_parent">
    <button class="bubu">0000</button>
    <button class="bubu">1111</button>
    <button class="bubu">2222</button>
    <button class="bubu">3333</button>
    <button class="bubu">4444</button>
</div>
```